# Why are the leaves of my peace lily plant turning yellow?

Tags: diagnosis, perennials, peace-lily

My peace lily plant was very robust and had lots of flowers. However, its leaves started turning yellow and now it looks like I am going to lose it.

What can I do?

Comment: picture please so we can give a better answer

Comment: @Marie Welcome! Please give us more information about your peace lily to help facilitate an answer. For instance, how and where you are growing the plant. Also, a couple of pictures of the plant would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

We need a picture really. But I’d say that the most common cause of plant death, especially house plants, is overwatering or over feeding as well as the wrong position in the house, making it bake in the sun!

It would be interesting to know how you approach all of the above!

Comment: Is it in the garden? Are you having a hot and dry season now? If it is potted, it is easy to check if the soil is dry or soggy. Soil in the garden tends to drain much better, but see first. If it suffers from drought stress, bottom leaves begin yellowing first.